# Find Tables in Image using C#

Tags: c#, imagemagick, emgucv, aforge, magick.net

I am trying to write a function that will take an image and return me a list of images with only tables using EMGU.CV or Magick.Net or AForge.Net
for example for the below image the function should return 2 images with the two tables in the image.

```
private static List<Image> FindTables(Image img)
{
    var masterImage = (Bitmap)img;
    var image = new Image<Gray, byte>(masterImage);
    var copyImg = new Image<Bgr, byte>(masterImage);
    List<Image> tables = new List<Images>
    //Find all tables and add to tables variable
    return tables;
}
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I was able to find all rectangles in an image using AForge's simple shape checker to fing quadrilaterals it is finding rectangles which are not even a part of a table in some images.

Comment: So how do you know whether a rectangle is just a rectangle or is part of a table. If you have a way of checking that, then you can filter out the ones you don't want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with connected components in Imagemagick. Filter out all regions that are small, which are text characters, leaving only the larger table outlines. Then get the bounding boxes for the tables and use those to crop the original image. Set the area-threshold so that the number of pixels in the lines of the table are larger than than the threshold and everything else is smaller than the threshold. (Unix syntax)

Input:
[image]

```
IFS=" "
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
bboxArr=(`convert image.png -alpha off -type bilevel \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-define connected-components:area-threshold=500 \
-connected-components 4 \
null: | grep "gray(0)" | awk '{print $2}'`)
num=${#bboxArr[*]}
IFS=$OLDIFS
for ((i=0; i<num; i++)); do
convert image.png -crop ${bboxArr[$i]} +repage image$i.png
done
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[image]

Sorry, I do not know Magick.NET. But you can discuss that with the Magick.NET developer by asking at  https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewforum.php?f=27 or at https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET

Comment: In what language is your code example written?

Comment: It is bash unix commands mixed with unix-style ImageMagick command line code.

Comment: Thank you, that helps! Incredible that you instantly answered on this old question. I like Stackoverflow ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can use Emgu CV to do this. Follow the following steps to recognize each cell on the table individually.
Install Emgu.Cv.runtime.windows to your project first and add the lines to the top of your file

```
using Emgu.Cv;
using Emgu.Cv.Struct;
```

Follow the following steps to recognize each cell on the table individually.

1. Load the input image into an Emgu CV struct

```
var image = new Image<Bgr, byte>("myimage.png");
```

2. Convert the image to grayscale

```
var gray = image.Convert<Gray, byte>();
```

3. Apply a binary threshold to the gray scale image

```
var binary = gray.ThresholdBinary(new Gray(100), new Gray(155));
```

4. Define a list to hold all the table cells found on the image

```
var cells = new List<Rectangle>();
```

5. Read all the contours from the image

```
 var contours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint();
 CvInvoke.FindContours(binary, contours, null, RetrType.List,ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);
```

6. Iterate through the contours to find the cells of the table by filtering out those which are too small (ie text) and checking the shape of the contour using the aspect ratio

```
//filter out text contours by checking the size
for (int i = 0; i < contours.Size; i++)
{
    //get the area of the contour
    var area = CvInvoke.ContourArea(contours[i]);
    //filter out text contours using the area
    if (area > 2000 && area < 200000)
     {
       //check if the shape of the contour is a square or a rectangle
       var rect = CvInvoke.BoundingRectangle(contours[i]);
       var aspectRatio = (double)rect.Width / rect.Height;
       if (aspectRatio > 0.5 && aspectRatio <= 5)
          {
              //add the cell to the list
              cells.Add(rect);
           }
      }
 }
```

7. Draw the cells on the Image using a color of your choice, I used brown color to highlight the cells

```
 if (cells.Count > 0)
    {
       foreach (var rect in cells)
        {
          image.Draw(rect, new Bgr(System.Drawing.Color.Brown),3);
        }
     }
```

8. Display the image with the cells highlighted.

```
CvInvoke.Imshow("Table Cells", image);
```

[image]

[image]

You can then use a relevant OCR library to scan for text from individual cells and use them in the program as you like.