# Equivalent OpenCV code for a Image Magick command

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, imagemagick, image-morphology

I am trying to pre-process my Images to remove Horizontal and Vertical Lines from them (required for some OCR). I got some Image Magick code to do the same which works fairly well. Below is the snippet:

```
magick convert ( img_name.jpg )    
( -clone 0 -morphology close rectangle:1x50 -negate +write tmp1.png )    
( -clone 0 -morphology close rectangle:50x1 -negate +write tmp2.png )    
( -clone 1 -clone 2 -evaluate-sequence add +write tmp3.png )
-delete 1,2     
-compose plus -composite    
result.jpg
```

This was obtained from the below link (full credit to them):

[Remove all horizontal and vertical lines from an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53955328/remove-all-horizontal-and-vertical-lines-from-an-image/53962592#53962592)

The thing is even though Image Magick works well it takes a very long time on high resolution Images (which is what I mostly have). So I am trying to convert the above snippet to Open CV Python code. I have already written partial Code for steps 1 and 2.

Step 1 and 2:

```py
img = cv2.imread('img_name.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
kernel_vertical = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,50))
kernel_horizontal = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (50,1))

temp_1 = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel_vertical)
#cv2.imwrite('temp_1.png',temp_1)

temp_2 = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel_horizontal)
#cv2.imwrite('temp_2.png',temp_2)
```

However I am unable to perform Step 3 and 4 because I am unsure what exactly the **evaluate-sequence** operator does. I have looked it up online but didn't understand well enough. If anybody is able to help me translate the remaining steps I would be very grateful.

Comment: -evaluate-sequence add simply does arithmetic addition of the two images with clipping to the range 0 to 255. The -compose plus adds tmp3 to input with clipping. (Two different ways to do image addition). Note that you need to invert the tmp1 and tmp2 images in Python (255-tmp1) and (255-tmp2), which is the equivalent of -negate in Imagemagick.  Note that properly in Imagemagick 7, use magick, not magick convert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the equivalent commands in Python/OpenCV.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('document.png')

# do morphology to locate vertical lines and invert
kernel_vertical = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,50))
temp1 = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel_vertical)
temp1 = (255-temp1)

# do morphology to locate horizontal lines and invert
kernel_horizontal = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (50,1))
temp2 = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel_horizontal)
temp2 = (255-temp2)

# add the two temp images together
temp = cv2.add(temp1, temp2)

# add temp to img to create result
result = cv2.add(temp, img)

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("document_lines_removed.png", result)

# display it
cv2.imshow("temp1", temp1)
cv2.imshow("temp2", temp2)
cv2.imshow("temp", temp)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. Accepting the answer :)

Comment: This is a very clever use of masking and bitwise operations. Thanks @fmw42, I may be borrowing this in the future :)

Comment: `@nathancy` No problem. Thanks. I have learned a lot from all your answer, too.